# Randomly generated content for a Webpage through Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, html

Is there any way of developing random content for a Webpage through using keywords and Google? This would random in a respect but within the peripheries of these keywords so content could be lightly directed to certain subject matter

Would the most sensible starting point to use a JQuery function? I was thinking the typewriter application could be a possible option

Any initial pointers would be very much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: So you want a web page where someone enters some keywords, and then that pages uses Google to find matches and adds random bits from result pages to your page? It's possible to do but I have no idea why you would want to do it.

Comment: that's it yeah. I've seen someone do it with specific web content, but maybe it's alot harder if the content isn't specified